# How i can get keys pressed in gui by user in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

How can I get a key pressed by the user? I'm trying to use the add hotkey gui but it doesn't work with space but in my script I need to allow the user to add any key

I tried use gui add, hotkey but, when i hit space didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Gui, Add, Hotkey, w300 h200 vhk
Gui, Show,, Hotkey Win

#IfWinActive Hotkey Win
    Space::
        GuiControlGet, ctrl, Focus
        if ctrl == msctls_hotkey321
            Sleep 10   ; idk why this is necessary
            GuiControl,, hk, Space
        return
#IfWinActive
```